# Troubleshooting accessing console of phpvirtualbox - TCP: SECURITY_ERROR Error #2048

Tags: server, virtualbox, php, firewall

Ok, so I just had a server crash tonight.

Reinstalled a backup Clonezilla image, restored website from tar/sql dump.

But whenever I "update" virtualbox I get an error and end up just uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

my phpvirtualbox is inside my website directory and got wiped as well.

The problem:

When I turn on virtualbox in PHPVirtualBox It turns on and gets IP and the small window to the right shows it boot to login screen as per usual.

But when I console after a bit of time I get

```
TCP: SECURITY_ERROR Error #2048
```

If I add (to config.php)

```
var $consoleHost = 'IP_of_server';
```

I get (in console window)

```
Disconnect reason: I: TCP: CLOSE: close
```

I think I have had this issue before but I didn't document it as I usually do! argg

So far I have chmod 777 the directory, turned off UFW and Fail2Ban and tried both NAT and Bridged Network Adapter inside PhPVirtualBox.

Their are posts all over the internet with this issue with only the tip above, but it didn't work for me, can anybody troubleshoot this with me? Any thoughts or guesses are appreciated!

Comment: I really hope this doesn't turn into the MANY [similar](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=65535)-[posts](https://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/issues/detail?id=621)-[like](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpvirtualbox/bugs/26/)-[this](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpvirtualbox/discussion/help/thread/4fe658be/) all with useless answeres to try var $consoleHost which I tried

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem. I solved removing any previous version of VirtualBox Extension Pack and installing version Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.6-103037 (you can find it here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0 ). Like you, i'm running VB5.0.8 and phpVB5.0.3; my OS is CentOS6.7; my kernel is 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64.
Maybe phpVB5.0.3 is not fully compatible with VB Extension Pack 5.0.8...we have to wait next release of phpVB ;)
Hope this help you.
Bye
Marco